# Why is it useful to use std::vector::reserve?

Tags: c++, vector

In C++, you can add elements to a vector by just using the push_back method. This method modifies the size of the vector.
Which is then the goal of using std::vector::reserve? When should I use it?

Comment: it is to minimize, or outright eliminate, buffer resizing and the hit that introduces (copying/moving can get expensive, especially for large numbers of objects). There is no `realloc` equivalent in the `operator new/delete` universe. To "expand" an allocation requires a separate allocation, much copying or moving, then a free of the old memory. By "declaring" your intent on magnitude, you can avoid that nuance. One mean rabbit is cute. A million mean rabbits is a helluva problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use reserve when you know that you will have at least n elements go into the vector. Resizing a container is a costly operation - you allocate new memory, copy the old content into it and then remove the old vector. If you know by default that you will get at least 10000 elements, it's better to reserve the size for the vector instead of letting the vector reallocate memory more times than necessary.

In simple words, it's all about the efficiency.

Comment: Even more important than efficiency: it guarantees that iterators remain valid.

Answer (score 4):

It can be used to ensure the validity of iterators, or as an optimization.  When adding elements to the vector, if the new size would be greater than the capacity, the vector must reallocate, copying (or moving) all of the existing elements into a new buffer.  This invalidates all iterators into the vector, and can be expensive.  The reserve function ensures a minimum capacity.  If you know in advance the maximum size, and do a reserve on it, adding elements will never invalidate iterators in front of the new element, and will never require copying.  (For most code, it is the issue of iterator validity that forces the use of reserve.)

Comment: So as a matter of best practice, one should always call reserve to avoid these kinds of side effects?

Comment: +1 It should be noted that even with an *ample* reserved buffer, one `insert(v.begin()...)` and the world falls apart regarding iterator validity. They *all* take it on the chin, even without a resize.

Comment: @staticx Not necessarily.  All lot of the time, for example, your doing the `push_back` in a relatively small loop, where it is clear that there are no iterators.  In such cases, there's no point in calling reserve (and when you can't set a reasonable upper bound on the final number of elements, you can't really use it effectively either).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes.  The original question mentioned `push_back`, which is probably the most frequent case.  When inserting at arbitrary points, you can generally forget about iterators.

Answer (score 2):

resizing vectors can significantly reduce execution speed (for example when appending a lot of data to it)

the reference says:

```
This effectively increases the container size by one, which causes an automatic
reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if- the new vector size
surpasses the current vector capacity.
```

so it helps to size the vector on a value where you ideally have enough for all your data and none left. the reduced resizing time of the vector will speed up your application

Answer (score 1):

It's for efficiency reasons - you can allocate memory for as much elements as you need, if you know that initally - this way the vector can allocate all at once and won't have to grow if it's exceeding the allocated size.

> [4] Reserve() causes a reallocation manually. The main reason for
>   using reserve() is efficiency: if you know the capacity to which your
>   vector must eventually grow, then it is usually more efficient to
>   allocate that memory all at once rather than relying on the automatic
>   reallocation scheme. The other reason for using reserve() is so that
>   you can control the invalidation of iterators.

[Source](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html)